# Query with 3 parameters to dynamodb with dynamoose

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, dynamoose

I am trying to consult a DynamoDB table with 3 parameters, but it does not work. However, with 1 parameter it works perfectly.

I'm work with NodeJs, DynamoDB, Dynamoose... and here is my code:

```
    var params = {

        TableName: "DifferentTermsPages",

        KeyConditionExpression:"#providerName = :providerName and #productType = :productType and #language = :language",

        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#providerName":"providerName",
            "#productType":"productType",
            "#language":"language"
            },

        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":providerName":providerName,
            ":productType":productType,
            ":language":language
            }

        };


       OcrController.getDifferencesFromDB(params)
        .then(function(dataDB) {
            console.log("DATA = ", dataDB); 
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(err);
       });
```

Call to another function with a promise:

```
  getDifferencesFromDB(params) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        DifferentTermsPagesModel.scan(params).exec().then(function (err, data) {
          if(err) {
            reject(err);
          }
          else {
            console.log("OK!!");
            resolve(data);
          }
        });

    });
  }
```

The error that shows me...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDynamo' of undefined
at Scan.exec (/API/src/node_modules/dynamoose/lib/Scan.js:57:23)
at ...
```

**Where is my error?? How can I resolve it? Or another form to make this...**

Comment: What are the key attributes of your table? Apparently, you cant have three attributes defined as keys.

Comment: The hashKey is an attibute called "id" and is unique, but I would like to search for those 3 parameters, can it be? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you are using the **scan api**, please use `FilterExpression` rather than `KeyConditionExpression`.

```
FilterExpression:"#providerName = :providerName AND #productType = :productType AND #language = :language",
```